# iterate through nltk dictionaries

Tags: python, nltk

I'd like to know whether it's possible to iterate through some of the available nltk dictionaries, ie: Spanish dictionary. I'd like to find certain words matching some requirements.

Let's say I got this list `["tv", "tb", "tp", "dv", "db", "dp"]`, the algorithm would give me words like `["tapa", "tubo", "tuba", ...]`. As you can see, if you get rid of the vowels in those words they'll be in the initial list:

- tapa => tp
- tubo => tb
- tuba => tb

Anyway, I just want to know whether it's possible to iterate through spanish words on nltk dictionaries and how, that's pretty much

Comment: I'm not sure if NLTK ships with a Spanish lexicon (there is a grammar resource, though). If there is, then you can most certainly iterate over its entries, probably by using the `.words()` method of a corpus object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nltk has plenty of Spanish language resources, but I'm not aware of a dictionary. So I'll leave the choice of wordlist up to you, and go on from there.

In general, the nltk represents wordlists as corpus readers with the usual method `words()` for the individual words. So here's how you could find words matching your template in the English wordlist:

```
templates = set(["tv", "tb", "tp", "dv", "db", "dp"])
for w in nltk.corpus.words.words("en"):
    <remove vowels and check if it is in `templates`>
```

I notice there's a Spanish stopwords list; here's how you would iterate over it:

```
for w in nltk.corpus.stopwords.words("spanish"):
    ...
```

You could also create your own "wordlist" from a Spanish-language corpus. I used the scare quotes because the best data structure for this purpose is a set. In python, iterating over a `set` or `dict` will give you its keys:

```
mywords = set(w.lower() for w in nltk.corpus.conll2002.words("esp.train"))
for w in mywords:
    ...
```

Comment: The 312 words are **stopwords**, not regular vocabulary. The English list is about the same size. Look on http://www.nltk.org/nltk_data/ for a list of the nltk data resources you can download (which is what you need-- not the list of readers in `nltk.corpus`). But of course you're not limited to the nltk's resources; you can find and load your own corpus from anywhere, with a bit of scripting on your own.

Comment: I misread your command, I was not expecting you to compare the **stopwords** list to a full dictionary. Edited my previous comment

Comment: I'm pretty sure you will not find a large vocabulary in `spanish_grammars`. The CONLL corpus I used as an example will give you about 23 thousand different words (some proportion are not real words, though). Try that first.

Comment: That's how long the text is. The number of different words is about 23000.

Comment: PS. Do yourself a favor and switch to Python 3 today. If you use Python 2 with any language other than English, you're asking for trouble.

Comment: Just use your internet smarts and go look for one. Why are you asking me? I don't even speak Spanish.